# Is there a quick way to obtain $a,b$ in $ax+by = z$ where $x,y,z$ are fixed and $x+1 = y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, algorithms

Suppose that all numbers are postive integers. Let $x,y,z$ be fixed/given and $x+1=y$. Then would there be a quick way to find set of solutions $(a,b)$ that satisfy $ax+by=z$? "Quick" would be subjective, but any way that does not involve brute-forcing would be fine.

Comment: Use $y = x+1$ to rewrite it to $(a+b)x + b = z$.

Comment: what are your thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

As $1=y-x $, we see that $ z=zy-zx $.

So $ a=-z, b=z $ is a solution.

Comment: but I said all numbers must be positive integers..

Comment: Once you have one solution, you have all solutions.  Adding x to a and subtracting y from b will give another.